# How to show edit text in action bar

Tags: android

EditText with Image Button:
[image]

I have created a edit text and image button for search. Now I want to show this edit text and search button in action bar like this:
Sample search view:
[image]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    etSearch= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
    btnSearch= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    search_list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mySearchList);

    http = new Http();
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("dbapp",MODE_PRIVATE);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            searchString=etSearch.getText().toString();

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
```

Comment: Actionbar depricated, use toolbar instead of it.

Comment: how to make a toolbar for search view please help me

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="Enter text"
        android:lines="1"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**#.** If you want to add `search` functionality on your `Toolbar`, then you can add `SearchView` on your Activity `menu` by using attribute `appcompat:actionViewClass`.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Here is good tutorial: [Android SearchView Action Bar Tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/)